# How do I check if a Firestore document exists before I update it?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm newish to Swift and new to Firestore and am running into an issue that I can't solve. I have the code below which is supposed to check for a document at the UserReference location in Firestore. If it doesn't exist, it should create a new document that contains the pertinent user information that I have previously grabbed from facebook.

This what UserReference looks like `self.UserReference = self.db.collection("users").document(UserID as! String)` where the UserID is from the Facebook graph request. Next, it'll run a transaction to pull the document, update the user doc with the latest facebook info (assuming this is not a new user), and then update the doc to Firebase Firestore.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var fbUserUpdate = User(
    firstName: String(),
    lastName: String(),
    email: String(),
    <extra stuff>)

func updateFacebookInfoToFirestore(completion: @escaping (_: User?, _: Error?) -> Void) {
    // Check if user exists, if not create new user
    UserReference!.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if document != nil {
            // continue
        } else {
            self.UserReference.setData(self.fbUserUpdate.dictionary)
        }
    }

    // Now pull data and update based on most recent facebook info.
    db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in

        // Read data from Firestore inside the transaction, so we don't accidentally
        // update using staled client data. Error if we're unable to read here.
        let UserSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot
        do {
            try UserSnapshot = transaction.getDocument(self.UserReference!)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            errorPointer?.pointee = error
            return nil
        }

        // This will overwrite the fbUserUpdate Struct with the updated information.
        guard var dbUser = User(dictionary: UserSnapshot.data()) else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "Domain", code: 0, userInfo: [
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to write to userdata at Firestore path: \(self.UserReference!.path)"
                ])
            errorPointer?.pointee = error
            return nil
        }

        // Update from Facebook
        dbUser.firstName = self.fbUserUpdate.firstName
        dbUser.lastName = self.fbUserUpdate.lastName
        dbUser.email = self.fbUserUpdate.email

        // Load new data to firestore
        transaction.setData(dbUser.dictionary, forDocument: self.UserReference!, options: SetOptions.merge())
        return nil
    }) { (object, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            // nothing yet
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this in my app, when I get to the `UserReference!.getDocument` closure, it skips over the closure and then the transaction doesn't work as intended because the `try UserSnapshot = transaction.getDocument(self.UserReference!)` returns a null since no document exists.

I believe the issue is in the `.getDocument` closure, but I don't know where I'm going wrong. I've tried to emulate the FriendlyEats firestore example code as best I can but I'm stuck and am in need of an extra set of eyes.

Comment: have you checked that UserReference has the correct path to the document?

Comment: So what I’m trying to do is check that the document exists at the location, and then if it doesn’t (where it returns nil) then I can create it and set the data in the first closure block. But I don’t think I’m doing it correctly since it isn’t working.